# large data shuffle causes timeouts

Tags: dask

I'm trying to read a 100000 data records of about 100kB each simultaneously from 50 disks, shuffling them, and writing it to 50 output disks at disk speed. What's a good way of doing that with Dask?

I've tried creating 50 queues and submitting 50 reader/writer functions using 100 workers (all on different machines, this is using Kubernetes). I ramp up first the writers, then the readers gradually. The scheduler gets stuck at 100% CPU at around 10 readers, and then gets timeouts when any more readers are added. So this approach isn't working.

Comment: How are you reading your records?  How are you shuffling?  I recommend providing a very small code example if convenient.  What does the dashboard look like when running?  http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web.html

Comment: You can see what I'm doing at this gist: https://gist.github.com/8b129e3f0b60963a2c748d1b866b9500 I've tried to cut the code down to its essentials. It works, but only for about 10 readers. Beyond that, the scheduler gets overwhelmed. Each read_fun generates records at several hundred per second. I can obviously imagine various workarounds involving batching to reduce load on the scheduler, but that's rather cumbersome. My question is how to express this kind of pattern nicely in Dask or whether Dask just isn't well suited to these communications patterns. (The dashboard is not informative.)

Answer (score 0):

Most dask operations have something like 1ms of overhead.  As a result Dask is not well suited to be placed within innermost loops.  Typically it is used at a coarser level, parallelizing across many Python functions, each of which is expected to take 100ms.

In a situation like yours I would push data onto a shared message system like Kafka, and then use Dask to pull off chunks of data when appropriate.

#### Data transfer

If your problem is in the bandwidth limitation of moving data through dask queues then you might consider turning your data into dask-reference-able futures before placing things into queues.  See this section of the Queue docstring: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Queue

> Elements of the Queue must be either Futures or msgpack-encodable data (ints, strings, lists, dicts). All data is sent through the scheduler so it is wise not to send large objects. To share large objects scatter the data and share the future instead.

So you probably want something like the following:

```
def f(queue):
    client = get_client()
    for fn in local_filenames():
        data = read(fn)
        future = client.scatter(data)
        queue.put(future)
```

#### Shuffle

If you're just looking to shuffle data then you could read it with something like dask.bag or dask.dataframe

```
df = dd.read_parquet(...)
```

and then sort your data using the set_index method

```
df.set_index('my-column')
```

Comment: Thanks. The 1ms overhead isn't the problem; the loops are fast enough. The same problem would occur with many queues even if there is more processing in the read_loop and write_loop. The problem seems to be that while reader, writer, and queues are distributed, the centralized scheduler still becomes a bottleneck even though the computation requires no centralized scheduling. The question is whether there is some other way of expressing such computations in Dask.

Comment: That's a useful hint and would help if the problem was bandwidth through the scheduler node. But futures would still be put into the queue through the central scheduler, wouldn't it? So it wouldn't really reduce the rate at which the scheduler needs to process message. It looks to me like even though Dask supports direct node-to-node communications, the scheduling of such communications still has to go through the central scheduler, which ends up being rate limiting for larger jobs. I'm just wondering whether I'm overlooking some other  construct for N-to-N communications in Dask.

Comment: I should say: I know of other solutions outside Dask. I'm looking for a simple, idiomatic solution that works for data scientists in Python, and Dask is otherwise a good fit. Dask compares itself to Spark http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/spark.html and claims to be able to "implement more sophisticated algorithms", but I don't see how I can use Dask to implement the Shuffle part of "Map-Shuffle-Reduce" for large datasets if all data movements of a shuffle need to get scheduled through the central scheduler.

Comment: If you're looking for a classic shuffle then I recommend using dask.bag or dask.dataframe.  It might help if you asked a new question with what you're trying to do, rather than asking a question with what you've tried.

Comment: I did ask about "what I'm trying to do", right there in the first paragraph: process and shuffle very large record-sequential data files in parallel. At this point, it seems to me that the O(N^2) load on the scheduler for these kinds of problems is intrinsic when using Dask's built-in communications. There are some workarounds I can build on top of Dask, but it seems like there is no standard solution/add-on for these kinds of problems right now. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to respond.